# Openssl FIPS version for iPhone armv7, armv7s & arm64

Tags: ios, openssl, fips

I'm trying to compile OpenSSL with the FIPS module for armv7, armv7s and arm64. The scripts I am using are

https://github.com/virtru/iOS-openSSL-FIPS/tree/develop

however, this script errors out with

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_FIPS_ec_group_new_curve_gf2m", referenced from:
      _EC_GROUP_new_curve_GF2m in libcrypto.a(ec_cvt.o)
  "_fips_ec_gf2m_simple_method", referenced from:
      _EC_GF2m_simple_method in libcrypto.a(ec2_smpl.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

I have also tried

https://gist.github.com/jostster/ebbc6925c668b632d8b185293080256c

which errors out with

```
./fips_standalone_sha1 fipscanister.o > fipscanister.o.sha1
/bin/sh: ./fips_standalone_sha1: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Does anyone have any experience and success with getting openssl to compile for iOS armv7, armv7s and arm64?

Update: For clarification I have followed the OpenSSL documentation and got it to build fine for armv7. However, my app supports armv7s and arm64 as well so it will not compile with the openssl fips armv7 version. Because of this I need to also compile openssl for the other platforms.

Comment: I built `armv7` and `armv7s` for FIPS a few years ago. I also helped document the procedures in [OpenSSL FIPS 140-2 User Guide 2.0](http://openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf). I don't recall `arm64` being an approved platform, but I have not been involved with it for quite some time. Generally speaking, it looks like (to me) that you are not following the published procedures. You should stop using other people's GitHub, and start using OpenSSL procedures. You definetly want to get familiar with the User Guide, Appendix E.2, APPLE IOS SUPPORT.

Comment: @jww I have used the user guide first. It is VERY outdated and doesn't include instructions for different architectures. armv8 was added last year.

Comment: Also see the [OpenSSL FIPS 140-2 Security Policy](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.pdf), It looks like the approved platforms are iOS 5.0 through 7.1. ARM64 (entries 100 and 101) are only valid for iOS 7.1. See Section 2 and the table that starts on page nine.

Comment: @jww from what I understood those are only the tested configurations.

Comment: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140sp/140sp1747.pdf states iOS 8.1 64 bit was added

Comment: @jww i also see where i could have confused readers. I have successfully built for armv7 using the documentation but now trying to build for armv7 + the other platforms is where I have issues.

Comment: For `FIPS_ec_group_new_curve_gf2m`, I believe you need to configure with `no-ec2m`. Maybe you should try again with the option. Also, you can't just reconfigure it. You have to delete the existing working folder, and re-untar it. Following that procedures sucks....

Comment: *"... states iOS 8.1 64 bit was added"* - Oh, my bad. I was using version 2.0.9 of the security policy. It looks like the [latest is 2.0.12](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.12.pdf). Also see the index of the warez at [Index of /docs/fips](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118661/discussion-between-bot-and-jww).

Comment: @jww i was able to build the fips module now. Do you mind chatting for some additional questions about getting the openssl library to compile?

Comment: Hi @Bot Are you able to compile the OpenSSL FIPS Library for arm64 architecture?

Comment: @iSpark the latest version of the gist i posted above should work with compiling or arm64

Comment: Does anyone have a set of instructions to build FIPS capable OpenSSL for arm64? Also another thing I wanted to check. I'm very new to development on Apple products. If I need to generate OpenSSL libraries for iOS 11.4, can I build it on mac?

Comment: Regarding "Bad CPU type in executable" error:
Openssl uses HOSTCC env var to build fips_standalone_sha1. So make it point to /usr/bin/clang